# Do Creatures have a gender?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

According to UESP, there are a total of sixteen [races](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Races) in Skyrim - ten playable, six non-playable:

- Playable

  - [Breton](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Breton)
  - [Imperial](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Imperial)
  - [Nord](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nord)
  - [Redguard](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Redguard)
  - [Altmer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Altmer)
  - [Bosmer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bosmer)
  - [Dunmer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dunmer)
  - [Orsimer](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Orc)
  - [Argonian](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Argonian)
  - [Khajiit](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Khajiit)
- Non-Playable

  - Breton Child
  - Imperial Child
  - Nord Child
  - Redguard Child
  - [Elders](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elder)
  - [Dremora](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dremora)

All other races in the game are classified separately as [Creatures](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Creatures).

For almost all of the above races, there are clear male and female varieties.  The one possible exception among those is Dremora - all the ones I've seen could most closely be defined as male, although they may in fact be gender-neutral.

Some of the Creature races seem to also have gender-specific appearances.

- Lower-level [Draugr](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Draugr#Draugr) appear to have male and female varieties.
- [Hagravens](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hagraven) appear exclusively female.
- [Giants](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Giant) appear exclusively male.
- [Flame Atronachs](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Flame_Atronach#Flame_Atronach) have a distinctly feminine appearance.
- [Ghosts](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ghost#Ghost) come in male and female forms.
- [Wispmothers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wispmother#Wispmother) are exclusively female.
- [Spriggans](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spriggan#Spriggans) come in [female-specific](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spriggan_Matron) and male/gender-neutral varieties.

My question is this:  In the guts of the game, where perk and blessing effects are calculated, do Creatures actually have a gender?  Are there more Creature races which are considered to have gender affiliations, in addition to the obvious ones I've noted here?  Or are all Creatures, regardless of appearance, considered neuter?

Comment: [Agent of Dibella](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Abilities#Abilities) is a relevant power for this question.

Comment: Dremora are a race, and have males and females like any other. I'm just not sure if there are any females in *Skyrim*, though there are some in Oblivion / SI.

Comment: One important thing about draugr is that their bodies don't seem to be generated male or female but rather randomly, so [the chicks can have beards](http://i.imgur.com/PbIWF.jpg). My first inclination is to believe creatures aren't given a gender -- if it's not working for humanoids like draugr I doubt it works elsewhere -- but I can't answer definitively.

Comment: @Bryan Interesting point, there. I can't say I've noticed that phenomenon myself before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 2-cents:

- There is no ActorValue for gender/sex (strangely enough), so no way to get it directly
- There is a console command (SexChange) for that, but it only changes the apparence of NPCs, not creatures. Furthermore, *it doesn't change the apparence of draugrs*.

Which means that:

- it has no effect on Creatures
- it works on Creatures, but most of them have only a mono-gender apparence (even 'female' draugrs)

Since it *can* change, I guess there must be a value for it, but I think it is more of an NPC-specific value (as in, value set during creation, like race or eyebrows color). Since Creatures are not generated the same way than NPC's (at least, as far as I know), I find it unlikely that they would be able to have a gender.

Hopefully, the SDK will answer more simply and directly :)